# VB.NET + Add folders to treeview and files to listview

Tags: vb.net, collections, directory

I want to create a simple printer manager to use in our Terminal server environment. Because of GPO restrictions, there are limits of what built-in functionality I can use. So I decided to try to write my own simple GUI to do that.

Now, the printers are distributed in a folder, with subfolders to categorize them. In each folder there are .lnk files to the actual printer on the printserver.

What I want to do is to populate a treeview with the folders, and the printers in a listview, based on which item is clicked on the treeview.

I've already managed to search for directories and to search the files for each item I've clicked. But I realized, why not use a collection or similar to do this during the startup of the form? That way, it'll be faster. Because right now, there's a small delay each time I click an item in the treeview. Because it scans for files each time.

How can I add the same to a collection and use that instead?

Here's my current code:

```
Public Sub populateTreeView(ByVal strPath As String)

        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(strPath)
        Dim diar1 As IO.DirectoryInfo() = di.GetDirectories()
        Dim dra As IO.DirectoryInfo

        For Each dra In diar1
            ImageList1.Images.Add(GetSmallIcon(dra.FullName))

            TreeView1.Nodes.Add("", dra.Name, nIndex)
            nIndex = nIndex + 1
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
        ListView1.Clear()
        nIndex = 0

        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(strIniSettings & "\" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text)
        Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

        For Each dra In diar1
            Dim strName As String
            strName = Replace(dra.Name, ".lnk", "")
            ImageList2.Images.Add(GetLargeIcon(dra.FullName))

            ListView1.Items.Add("", strName, nIndex)
            nIndex = nIndex + 1
        Next
    End Sub
```

Notice the Imagelists? I also get the Icon for each item as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is not complex, a simple [`LookUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) may be the right collection for you (or just a plain Dictionary).

Just query the printers once, and store it in a member variable, or just use the `Tag` property of the `TreeNode`s so store the file names.

In the example below, I'm using a simple Linq query to create a `LookUp` where the `Key` is the directory name (you could also just use full path to the directory), and the items are the file names.

You could then either query the collection by a given `Key` (the directory name), or use the `Tag` property.

---

**LINQPad example:**

```
Sub Main

    ' query printers once (just replace C:\test with your path)
    ' store the result in a member variable of your form
    Dim printer = new DirectoryInfo("C:\test").GetDirectories() _
                                              .SelectMany(Function(d) d.GetFiles()) _
                                              .ToLookup(Function(f) f.Directory.Name, Function(f) f.Name)

    ' Or, using a Dictionary
    ' Dim printer = new DirectoryInfo("C:\test").GetDirectories() _
    '                                           .ToDictionary(Function(d) d.Name, Function(d) d.GetFiles().Select(Function(f) f.Name).ToList())



    Dim l = new ListView() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Right}
    Dim t = new TreeView() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Left}                    
    AddHandler t.AfterSelect, Sub(s, e)
                                    ' This is your AfterSelect event handler
                                    ' The filenames are stored in the Tag of the TreeNode
                                    ' You could also use 'For Each p As String in printer(e.Node.Text)'
                                    l.Items.Clear()
                                    For Each p As String in e.Node.Tag
                                        Dim item = l.Items.Add(p.Replace(".lnk", ""))
                                        'TODO: Set Icon on item
                                    Next
                              End Sub

    ' Populate TreeView once
    For Each folder in printer
        Dim fNode = t.Nodes.Add(folder.Key)
        'TODO: Set Icon on fNode

        ' store the files in the Tag of the node.
        ' You don't have to, but it will make it easier
        fNode.Tag = folder
    Next

    ' Show test form            
    Dim w = new Form()
    w.Controls.Add(t)
    w.Controls.Add(l)
    w.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: That would do it! Thank you! :) I'll have to do some changes to the code though, I don't want to create the controls on the fly like this. But that's just a minor task :)